# Using ViewModel with foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

I have a simple scenario, but can't figure out how to setup a ViewModel. I have a `CustomerController.cs`, `Create.cshtml`, and `Edit.cshtml`. On these views I have fields to take in basic customer information like Name, Phone, Fax, Email.

There is a foreign key in my `Customer` table called `AddressId`. The `Address` table consists of columns like `AddressId, Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip`.

I am using Entity Framework so I can simply get a customer's address by doing `Customer.Address`

My form consists of both the customer and address fields which is where my confusion comes in. Do I need all of the address fields, do I at least need `AddressId` which is the foreign key, do I not need `AddressId`, but simply `Address`, etc..

Here is what I currently have in my `CustomerInfoViewModel`:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Phone { get; set; }
public string Fax { get; set; }
public int AddressId { get; set; }
//Address fields
public string Address1 { get; set; }
public string Address2 { get; set; }
public string City { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "State")]
public int StateId { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Zip Code")]
public string ZipCode { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Country")]
public int CountryId { get; set; }
```

I have a `State` and `Country` dropdown on the page so I figured I would only need the Ids of `State` and `Country`. So I am confused on whether I do all of the above or rather than add all of the `Address` fields simply add:

```
public Address Address { get; set; }
```

Comment: One advantage of your current `CustomerInfoViewModel` is that you have the flexibility to add view specific validation attributes (for example you might have `[RegularExpression]` attribute applied to `ZipCode`). The view model should also include properties for the SelectList's your using for `State` and `Country`

Answer (score 0):

You should able to do it either. The biggest deciding factor is if you want to pull in and bind properties to the view model or the entity model. So whether you decide:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(CustomerInfoViewModel vm)
```

Or

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Customer model)
```

It's really more about code style.